# где редактировать MX записи у регистратора домена или на хостинге?

Tags: веб-программирование, dns, email, hosting

есть домен купленый у руцентра, который делегирован на хостинг бегет. создан корпоративный почтовый ящи почтовый ящик с адресом xxx@мойдомен.ру. где требуется редактировать мх записи для привязки к яндекс почте, на хостинге или у регистраторна домена то есть на руцентре?

Comment: У регистраторов доменов очень редко есть DNS-хостинг. В бегете есть редактирование DNS. Там и правьте, если домен привязан.

Comment: `DNS` записи меняются на конечном `DNS` хостинге, если у вас на стороннем сервисе куплен домен и вы делегировали его на другой хостинг, вам необходимо изменять `DNS` записи на последнем

Answer (score 0):

> домен … делегирован на хостинг

вот куда делегировали обслуживание доменных записей для вашего доменного имени — туда и надо обращаться по поводу добавления новых доменных записей.

---

но вообще, если есть желание, можно и «раскопками» заняться. на примере `мойдомен.рф`.

смотрим, какие ns-ы обслуживают это доменное имя:

```
$ dig ns мойдомен.рф
;мойдомен.рф.       IN  NS
мойдомен.рф.    299 IN  NS  ns2.airy-host.ru.
мойдомен.рф.    299 IN  NS  ns1.airy-host.ru.
```

именно они и должны отдавать mx-записи для этого доменного имени. типа таких (для этого доменного имени записи уже созданы, а для вашего список будет пустой):

```
$ dig mx мойдомен.рф
;мойдомен.рф.       IN  MX
мойдомен.рф.    299 IN  MX  10 mx1.airy.host.
мойдомен.рф.    299 IN  MX  20 mx2.airy.host.
```

по самому доменному имени этих ns-ов — `airy-host.ru` — уже, думаю, владелец доменного имени `мойдомен.рф` сможет однозначно идентифицировать, куда именно следует обращаться для создания/изменения mx-записей.